# Call a same method 500 times in java

Tags: java, selenium

Hi I need to call a method "loop()" 500 times. Do I need to write "loop();" 500 times or is there any method to call it multiple times. Please help with this. The following code is in java and I am doing this with selenium webdriver.

```
public class Salesforce_login {
public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:/Users/Master/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    // driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("https://login.com");
    driver.findElement(
            By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginSwitcher:loginSwitcherForm']/div[1]/div[1]/div/a"))
            .click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(
            "*****");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys(
            "*****");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Login']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(30000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='moreGroupMembersLink']"))
            .click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    loop();
    loop();
    loop();
    loop(); 


}
    public static void loop() throws InterruptedException{
    for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        System.out.println(driver
                .findElement(
                        By.xpath(".//*[@id='groupMembersDialogContent']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[2]/div/a"))
                .getAttribute("href"));
    }
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='groupMembersDialogContent']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/span[2]/span[1]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't get strain. Use loops.

Comment: **Watch out:** you have 24 * `Thread.sleep(2000);` in `loop()` , so running the method 500 times will consume about **6.5 hours**...

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {` this loop runs **24** times

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      loop();
}
```